# Go test fails in Emacs lsp-mode with gopls, but succeeds in shell

Tags: go, emacs

When I try to run a [test](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/add-a-test) by clicking "run test" in Emacs using `lsp-mode` here (image attached), I get a message saying:

```
LSP :: 1 / 1 tests failed
package command-line-arguments is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.16/libexec/src/command-line-arguments)
```

However, when I run the tests in my terminal, they pass:

```
❯ go test -v
=== RUN   TestHelloName
--- PASS: TestHelloName (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestHelloEmpty
--- PASS: TestHelloEmpty (0.00s)
PASS
ok      example.com/greetings   0.078s
```

This is already peculiar because that's not the value for `GOROOT` that I've set in my `.zshrc`. When I check `*lsp-log*` , I can see that `GOROOT` there is set as `GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.16/libexec`, but when I run `echo $GOROOT` in my terminal, it's `/usr/local/opt/go/libexec` (which I've set in my `.zshrc`. Firstly, what's going on with the missing `command-line-arguments` package? Secondly, why is `gopls` seeing a different `GOROOT` from what I've set in my `.zshrc`?

I already use `exec-path-from-shell`  to ensure that Emacs has the same env variables as my shell, so how come `gopls` doesn't seem to see those?

[image: inline test]

Comment: Please do not submit the same question to both emacs.SE and StackOverflow. Choose one to keep and delete the other. Thx.

Comment: Sure, I've deleted the emacs.SE one. Thanks!